# Why does Babel transpile console.log into (_console = console).log.apply(_console, ... )?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

The line

```
console.log(1, 3, 5, ...[2, 4, 6])
```

is transpiled by Babel as:

```
"use strict";

var _console;

(_console = console).log.apply(_console, [1, 3, 5].concat([2, 4, 6]));
```

why does it have to use `_console`?  I tried

```
console.log.apply(console, [1, 3, 5].concat([2, 4, 6]));
```

and it works equally well in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, MSEdge, IE11, and Node.

Comment: It's probably because of the spread syntax. If you call it with just `console.log(1, 3, 5)`, it doesn't do this.